# retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 504 Unsatisfiable Request (only-if-cached) kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp, cache-control

I want to cache the response for 2 hours and hence, tried adding cache to my okhttp client, every time hitting API with the network it works fine but next time, enabling airplane mode, we try fetching data in Offline mode, it gives retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 504 Unsatisfiable Request (only-if-cached)
I have tried every solution related to this exception posted here on SO. Please help me find out what am I doing wrong...been stuck at this for really long.

```
interface TrendingRepoService {

@GET("/repositories?language=&since=daily")
suspend fun getTrendingRepos() : List<Repo>
}

object RetrofitClient {
  private fun getClient(context: Context): Retrofit {
    val cacheSize = (5 * 1024 * 1024).toLong()    //cache size is 5mb
    val myCache = Cache(File(context.cacheDir, "responses"), cacheSize)
    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cache(myCache)
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                var request = chain.request()
                if (hasNetwork(context)!!) {
                    request.newBuilder().removeHeader("Pragma")
                            .addHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + 5)
                } else {
                    request = request.newBuilder()
                            .removeHeader("Pragma")
                            .addHeader("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + 60 * 60 * 2)  //cache should expire after 2 hours
                            .build()
                }

                println("network: " + chain.proceed(request).networkResponse())
                println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + myCache.directory().lastModified())
                println("cache: " + chain.proceed(request).cacheResponse())
                chain.proceed(request)
            }
            .build()

    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl("https://github-trending-api.now.sh")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
            .build()
   }
 fun getTrendingService(context: Context): TrendingRepoService {
    return getClient(context).create(TrendingRepoService::class.java)
}
}
```

I can see the following files in my app cache folder

[image]

The contents of file stored .0.tmp ending file in cache

```
https://github-trending-api.now.sh/repositories?language=&since=daily 
GET
0
HTTP/1.1 200 
14
date: Mon, 04 Nov 2019 19:27:43 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
x-powered-by: Express
access-control-allow-origin: *
etag: W/"4fcb-tcvKxcVttStpWpvGjIHTyk/TMbU"
cache-control: max-age=120
x-now-trace: hel1,bru1,sfo1
x-now-id: hel1:rv96m-1572895662521-476640337170
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000
x-now-instance: 4008292682
content-encoding: gzip
server: now
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1572895661313
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1572895662894

TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
2
MIIFTzCCBDegAwIBAgISA4Bu+MYBP......
0
TLSv1.3
```

How max-age is 120?? Every time I am getting 504 error when I want to fetch data with cache.
When I hit API with no network only journal file exists in my cache folder the other two files are not there the next time.

Comment: Add code with request your are performing, and trying to make work offline.

Comment: I have edited the question, there is no extra code to make it offline.

Comment: What REQUEST, you are doing with offline cache?

Comment: @GensaGames the problem was singleton. Client was creating different object everytime

Comment: Lol, really, there is function return new `okhttpclient` each time.